# How to migrate a database from SQL server to Oracle?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, migration

I have been assigned a task to migrate a database from SQL server to Oracle.
But I have no idea about how to do it.

Also, is there any need to change the existing data model?

Comment: Pls explain the process step-by-step

Comment: What is a "pls"?

Comment: there where whole books written about this subject. Some of them were recommended in this site too. Use Google, search on SO.

Answer (score 4):

There are two very detailled documents [here](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/hol08/sqldev_migration/mssqlserver/migrate_microsoft_sqlserver_otn.htm) and [here](https://taliphakanozturken.wordpress.com/2012/11/29/migration-from-sql-server-to-oracle-using-sql-developer/). There is a step by step guide (with videos) [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/migration/sqlserver-095136.html). It is no coincidence that two of these documents are from Oracle themselves, it being very much in their interest to get clients to move from SQL Server to their product.

Your question is a bit too vague and general for this forum, but since you're new to dba.stackexchange, I'll let that pass. I obtained these links by simply Googling - you should do this before you ask questions here. Show us that you've done a bit of work - then ask more specific questions.

Take the [tour](https://dba.stackexchange.com/tour) and also check out the "[help us to help you](http://dba.blogoverflow.com/2012/06/help-us-help-you/)" blog (both at the bottom left of the page).

Dba.stackexchange is a great resource and you will get all the more out of it by following the guidelines in the posts above. Finally, welcome to the forum! :-)

Comment: Thanks for the immediate and HELPFUL reply Vérace.. Appreciate it very much..!!